# Postfix owner mail loop 'owner-owner-owner-owner-owner-owner-owner...'

Tags: postfix, email-server

Our postfix logs are being filled with messages that appear to be stuck in the mail queue.

I believe this may have been caused by a recent DNS outage. The offending mail was originally intended for `node@hostname` but postfix was unable to resolve its own domain.

However, what I don't understand is why the messages have been prefixed with `owner-owner-owner-owner-owner-`. This is repeated hundreds of times - the mail address is so long that the postfix logs truncate it so I can't even see the original address without using `mailq`.

Does anyone know why this happens? What is postfix trying to achieve by prefixing with owner and how do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but does the condition persist if you clear the queue?

Comment: I cleared these messages from the queue and they haven't come back since, which does suggest the DNS outage was the trigger for this. I would still like to understand what postfix was doing though.